# Замена кнопки submit в форме

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте.
Есть такая форма

```
<form id="target" action="http://dev.1-11.ru/forma/php_word.php" method="post">
        <input  type="hidden" name="image" value='<?php echo $image_doc; ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value='<?php echo $product_name; ?>'>
        <input  type="hidden" name="articul" value='<?php echo $catalogVars['goodsArticle']; ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="cost" value='<?php echo $catalogVars['goodsPrice']; ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="parametrs" value='<?php

        foreach ($catalogVars['charAll'] as $char) {
            $parametrs= $parametrs.$char[charName].': '. $char[charValue].'; ';
        }
        echo base64_encode($parametrs);
        ?>'>

        <p align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value=""></p>
    </form>
```

Данная форма невидима, как сделать кнопку за пределами данной формы что бы она выполняла функции `input type="submit"`?

Answer (score 1):

Доброе утро. если правильно понял ваш вопрос, то надо сделать что-то типа такого:

```
$('#your-btn).click(function(){
$('#target').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать - [атрибут form](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/form)

```html
<form id="target" method="" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" required />
</form>

<input type="submit" form="target" />
```